# Wicked_PDF not rendering correct template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

Hi I have an application for writing proposals. I am trying to set up wicked_pdf to generate pdf's and for some reason its not using the correct template. its using my application template, not my pdf template.

app/controllers/proposals_controller.rb

```
def show
    @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
    @custom_content = @proposal.custom_contents
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "some_name",
               template: "proposals/show.pdf.erb",
               layout: "pdf.html",
               margin: { top: 35, bottom: 35 }
      end
    end
  end
```

app/views/layouts/pdf.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PDF</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" -%>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container d-flex justify-content-center'>
  test 2
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app/views/proposals/show.pdf.erb

```
<div class="row full-page justify-content-center" id="cover">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row p-0">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-end ">
        <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag '1209232_1920-1.jpg' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-1 d-flex align-items-end text-justify">
      <div class="col-12 text-justify cover-background">
        <div class="row pt-1">
          <h2 class="text-white text-justify">Proposal For <br> Maintenance</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-0">
          <div class="col-6">
            <h5 class="text-white text-justify">Prepared For: <%= @proposal.contact.name %></h5>
            <h6></h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <h5 class="text-white text-justify">Prepared By: <%= @proposal.user.name %></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb

```
# WickedPDF Global Configuration
#
# Use this to set up shared configuration options for your entire application.
# Any of the configuration options shown here can also be applied to single
# models by passing arguments to the `render :pdf` call.
#
# To learn more, check out the README:
#
# https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/README.md

WickedPdf.config = {
    }
```

config/initializers/mime_types.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

I feel like I have looked at this so long, that I am probably missing the obvious. I have even run up a sample app to test... and had no issues with that one.

I followed along with this great tutorial - https://medium.com/@yazed.jamal/using-wicked-pdf-with-rails-5-3d1a4b0a09ba

Any help is much appreciated

the other thing to note is that the file created is not "some_name" but the id .pdf

my button is located in my app/views/proposals/_proposal-cover.html.erb
which is a partial in my app/views/proposals/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Download', proposal_path(@proposal, :format => :pdf), class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
```

Comment: Check this video its about  how to convert Ruby html to pdf file with gem 'prawn' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW5zwqj37Lo&t=625s

Comment: @nourza you think give up on wicked_pdf?

Comment: Not sure but I am looking in the github page. Did you install this gem gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary' ?

Comment: @nourza sure did

Comment: I think because of the render in the proposals_controller.rb here def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "file_name"   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
      end
    end
  end

Comment: @nourza changed name, same issue.... its not finding the template file.... the template setting is to tell the app which template to be used when rendering the pdf, while layout setting is where wicked_pdf utilize the main application layout to be rendered

Comment: Did you checked this https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMOtbqd4aCQ

Comment: Yes ofcourse the github repo was checked @nourza

Comment: Could you paste your show.html.erb concerning the link?

Comment: @DollarChills added as edit at bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to say thanks to @dollarchills and @nourza. Both were great helps with this one.

It turns out that the other developer had installed the following

> If you would like to have WickedPdf automatically generate PDF views
>   for all (or nearly all) pages by appending .pdf to the URL, add the
>   following to your Rails app:

## in application.rb (Rails3) or environment.rb (Rails2)

```
require 'wicked_pdf'
config.middleware.use WickedPdf::Middleware
```

which overwrites everything else

Answer (score 2):

Give the following a try. I use wicked in my application, and this structure works for me, hope it does for you.

Show

```
<%= link_to 'Download', proposal_path(format: 'pdf'), class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
```

**Controller**

```
format.pdf do
 render pdf: "some_name",
  template: "proposals/show",
  margin: { top: 35, bottom: 35 }
end
```